# Is it OK to end a sentence with an object pronoun (e.g. "He aprendido mucho de los")

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronombres, objetos-directos

I'm trying to tell someone that I've learned a lot from a set of videos and books: "***Thanks a lot for your excellent books and videos. I have learned a lot from them.***" and so my attempted translation was: "***Muchas gracias para tus libros y videos excelentes. He aprendido mucho de los.***"

Is this correct? Can I end a sentence with "de los" like this to mean "from them"? For some reason, something about it seemed off ... if this is incorrect, what would be the best way to translate this type of sentence - i.e. "*I have **_** from them*"?

Gracias!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*los* is an article. The right pronoun in this case is *ellos*. Otherwise it is a perfectly correct sentence, with a couple corrections:

> Muchas gracias **por** tus excelentes libros y videos. He aprendido mucho de ellos.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is **incorrect**. *los* is sometimes an article and sometimes a personal pronoun.  See http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=los

Comment: I disagree.  `Ellos` is the best possible option given the other pronouns (aquellos, esos, estos).  It would be better to say `Me han enseñado muchos esos libros` though. but that isn't a direct translation, and would be out of context a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Sí, se puede terminar una oración con un pronombre.

Esta te suena mal, porque el **pronombre** (que no artículo) `los` está en acusativo, y cuando se usa preposición, el pronombre de 3ª persona plural que debe usarse es `ellos`.

`Les` y `los` se usan siempre sin preposición, y cuando van tras el verbo se escriben junto a él. Sin embargo, ese tipo de construcción, salvo en imperativo, es anticuado y ya no se usa.

> Aprendí mucho de **ellos**.
>
> Esos temas, aprénde**los**.
>
> Aprendió**los**. *(Anticuado; hoy se dice “Los aprendió”.)*

Comment: La posposición fuera del contexto imperativo todavía es corriente en el habla del noroeste de España, por influencia del gallego y asturiano.  Por ejemplo «voyme», «díjele», etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can (you use the pronoun to refer to something that you have already named in the same sentence), **but** when you are saying

> ... he aprendido mucho de **los**.

you are actually **ending the sentence with an *articucle*, not a pronoun**. That's why it sounds off. You are actually saying, "I have learnt a lot form *the*", not "I have learnt a lot from *them*".

Some examples of pronouns are **este, aquel, unos, alguien**, etc.

On the other hand **el, la, lo, los** and **las** are *articulos*.

Check [here](http://roble.pntic.mec.es/msanto1/lengua/1determi.htm) if you want some more quick clues about *articulos and determinantes*.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is **incorrect**. *los* is sometimes an article and sometimes a personal pronoun. See lema.rae.es/drae/?val=los

Comment: Examples from your link: "Los miré. Míralos". "Míralos" and "Mira los" are NOT the same thing. Nobody is saying that it can't be a pronoun, only that used like that it is not. Hearing that, every Spanish speaker would think that there is a missing "libros" after that "los".